# Loop into an array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
$array = [
    ['2017-02-26', '2017-02-27'],
    ['2017-03-01'],
    ['2017-01-01', '2017-01-02', '2017-01-03', '2017-01-04'],
    ['2017-01-05', '2017-01-06', '2017-01-07']
];
```

I'm looking to loop into this array to have something like this:

// When several dates

- From `2017-02-26 to 2017-02-27`.

// When only one date

- On the `2017-03-01`.

What I tried:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $count = count($array[$key]);
    if($count==1) {
        echo "On the $key[$value]";
    }
    else {
        $first = reset($array);
        $last = end($array);
        echo "From ".$first." to ".$last.;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work when there is only one date in the row.

Comment: The OP knows how to access array data, this is a Typo question.

Answer (score 2):

You are looping by `foreach()` so it will display last echo string .Store result to one variable Eg(`$display`) will be more easy to display that

```
$display = "";
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $count = count($array[$key]);
    if($count==1) {
        $display .=  "On the $value[0] <br>";
    }
    else {
        $first = $value[0];
        $last = $value[$count-1];        
        $display .= "From ".$first." to ".$last."<br>";
    }
}
echo $display;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $count = count($value);
    if($count==1) {
        echo "On the ".$value[0];
    }
    else {
        $first = reset($value);
        $last = end($value);
        echo "From ".$first." to ".$last;
    }
}
```

Or just copy paste this code, it will work. Your main inside array to play with is **$value**.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this answer doesn't seem to try to educate the OP/researchers -- it just says: copy this code.